# How do I create a 2d index on two distinct keys of a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The structure of my collection is as follows:

```
{
latitude:
longitude:
metric1: 
metric2:
metric3:
}
```

I want to create a 2d index using latitude and longitude keys.

I know it can be done by creating a separate location field carrying latitude and longitude values. But, I do not want to change the structure of the current collection. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: What stops you to use the loc filed? If it is possible, probably it will not be the best solution, in comparison with using the loc field.  You can easily postprocess the fields in your app if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You need to construct the location field in the way MongoDB's geospatial indexes expect is. For a 2d index, you use legacy coordinate pairs

```
{
    "loc" : [<longitude>, <latitude>],
    "metric1" : <value>,
    "metric2" : <value>,
    "metric3" : <value>
}
```

For a 2dsphere index, you use GeoJSON

```
{
    "loc" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [<longitude>, <latitude>] },
    "metric1" : <value>,
    "metric2" : <value>,
    "metric3" : <value>
}
```